# asp.net webform keep keep being authenticated in an mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, webforms

I have a well-running mvc4 application with Forms authentication. Then I need to do some report with ReportViewer, so I have to add a webform page with an ReportViewer inside and put in an iframe in an mvc Razor page.

The problem is when I browse that webform (even directly or from the Controller.Action that return the Razor page with iframe embbeded), a basic anthentication form keeps being displayed and asked for a username/password.

Even I have added this to web.config

```
 <location path="pathToWebForm.aspx">
   <system.web>
     <authorization>
       <allow users="*"/>
     </authorization>
   </system.web>
 </location>
```

Please help on how to remove this basic authentication form from the webform.
Thanks in advance.

UPDATED: The authentication form ONLY appears if I put the webform inside a folder. Everything goes well if the webform is in root folder of application.

Comment: just check path of aspx page it should be correct...

Comment: Thanks @Exception, I just put it inside Reports folder in root app, the path is "Reports/WebFormName.aspx" or even tried with "Reports"